# Copy/paste command not working on my iPad Air after the latest update IOS 16.3 using Logitech keyboard

Tags: ios, ipad

Earlier, I always used to copy and paste text using <kbd>Alt/Cmd</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and then <kbd>Alt/Cmd</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>. This is before 16.3 version of iOS.  16.2 and earlier are all OK.

Now, suddenly after the latest update, it is not working. What it does is that <kbd>Alt/Cmd</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> gives me a comma (,) and <kbd>Alt/Cmd</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> gives me the inverted caret or caron symbol (ˇ).

What can I do to fix it? I checked online, but nothing worked.

Also to note;

I tried the 4 commands present on my keybaord:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Fn</kbd> <kbd>Start/Alt</kbd> <kbd>Alt/Cmd</kbd> while using <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd>

Just for better clarity , I marked the four keys in blue on this photo of my Logitech keyboard.

[image]

Comment: Did you check the language settings?

Comment: Note that Alt is the OPTION key and Command/Cmd is a different key entirely, and Option-C just gives you this: ç . So Alt/Cmd is either two different keys or a combination of the both that does not copy or paste.

Comment: @Allan Waht do i exactly check in langauge settings ? From what i tried is to check if by going to keybaord hardware -> language settings -> English. Is that what u meant ?

Comment: @SteveChambers I tried all the ones possible too.

Comment: @SteveChambers It worked fine earlier

Comment: I’m using a Logitech K380 BT with an iPad running iPadOS 16.2 and it works as it should.  If the language setting is correct, check the keybindings and try a different App to see if it’s app specific.

Comment: Looking at last edit, why are you pressing `Fn`?

Comment: @Allan, he noted that in 16.2 it was working for him as well, but it stopped working in 16.3. Maybe update and see if yours stops as well, then we'll have some proof if this is a general issue

Comment: Thanks at @YisroelTech.  That was a typo on my part.  I am running 16.3

Comment: The keyboard looks like it is confusingly labeled. On *most* Windows keyboards the "Start" key usually has the windows logo and is mapped to command. Not so on that keyboard also that keyboard has *another* keycap labeled "alt" and command. You may want to turn on the keyboard viewer and see what keys macOS is using for what keypress. It's in System Settings >Keyboard > Keyboard Layouts > show input menu in menu bar.

Comment: Sorry, this is iPadOS not macOS, I don't have one of those for reference and a keyboard viewer...